# ActiveMQ + Stomp, Reading one message but four of them get dequeued

Tags: php, queue, activemq-classic, stomp

When I read one message from AMQ with Stomp I get 3 or 4 messages dequeued, don't know why.

Code for populating AMQ:

```
public function populate($queue, $c = 10) {

    for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $this->stomp->send($queue,' Random populated:'.rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX));
    }

}
```

[image: ActiveMQ Queue after populating]
[image: ActiveMQ messages after populating]

Code for reading AMQ:

```
public function read($queue = null) {

    if(is_null($queue)) {
        if(!$this->isSubscribed()) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $this->subscribe($queue);
    }

    return $this->stomp->readFrame();

}
```

Stomp readFrame() code:

```
public function readFrame ()
{
    if (!$this->hasFrameToRead()) {
        return false;
    }

    $rb = 1024;
    $data = '';
    $end = false;

    do {
        $read = fread($this->_socket, $rb);
        if ($read === false) {
            $this->_reconnect();
            return $this->readFrame();
        }
        $data .= $read;
        if (strpos($data, "\x00") !== false) {
            $end = true;
            $data = rtrim($data, "\n");
        }
        $len = strlen($data);
    } while ($len < 2 || $end == false);

    list ($header, $body) = explode("\n\n", $data, 2);
    $header = explode("\n", $header);
    $headers = array();
    $command = null;
    foreach ($header as $v) {
        if (isset($command)) {
            list ($name, $value) = explode(':', $v, 2);
            $headers[$name] = $value;
        } else {
            $command = $v;
        }
    }
    $frame = new StompFrame($command, $headers, trim($body));
    if (isset($frame->headers['transformation']) && $frame->headers['transformation'] == 'jms-map-json') {
        require_once 'Stomp/Message/Map.php';
        return new StompMessageMap($frame);
    } else {
        return $frame;
    }
    return $frame;
}
```

I'm 100% sure that code is being executed exactly once but the result is:
[image: ActiveMQ queue after reading one message]
[image: ActiveMQ messages after reading one message]

Var_dumped message:

```
object(StompFrame)[4]
public 'command' => string 'MESSAGE' (length=7)
public 'headers' => 
array (size=5)
  'message-id' => string 'ID:**********_-49723-1350635513276-2:1:-1:1:1' (length=45)
  'destination' => string '/queue/test' (length=11)
  'timestamp' => string '1350635842968' (length=13)
  'expires' => string '0' (length=1)
  'priority' => string '4' (length=1)
public 'body' => string 'Random populated:1859256320' (length=27)
```

Does anyone know what can be the cause of this behavior?

Notices:

- There is no ack of message so not even one message should be dequeued :|
- ACK is in client mode
- Prefetch size is set to 1

Comment: Debugging what? My script, Stomp or ActiveMQ? My script is doing one connection and one readFrame() which is var_dumped as above, no loops, no frameworks, simple flat php. I added Stomp->readFrame() code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see you connect code but I'm going to assume you are connecting using Auto Ack mode.  In STOMP with Auto Ack mode the messages are ack'd as soon as they hit the wire and since I'm also assuming you didn't change the prefetch size the broker will send you a batch of messages so as you read them from the socket and more can be sent more will get dequeued.  If you want more fine grained control over message consumption you should use another ack mode like client ack and ack each message as it arrives.  You can also set the prefetch window for your subscription to reduce the number of messages that are batched to your client.

See this [page](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) for the AMQ STOMP configuration options.  You may also want to look over the STOMP spec again.

Comment: The ack is in client mode, prefetch size is set to 1.

Comment: You should add the connect code, otherwise this is not clear in the questions.